# How do I hook API to get realtime stock price data?

Tags: windows, windows-10

How I can hook SSL API from proprietary software.

I want to extract realtime stock price data from stock trade software that provided by securities company.

There is no API in this software. And This software is not open source.

This software worked on my pc.

I have tried inspect connection with wireshark, but it is encrypted. I know that connection between client software and server is encrypted.

So I need decrypt SSL connection.
I suppose that it need hook SSL API But I don't know how to do it.

How I can do it?

My Environment:
Windows 10 Home 1709

Comment: You can not decrypt the SSL traffic. But you can try a MiTM: install a proper certificate on one of your server and divert the application traffic to it. If you are lucky it will just test the TLS connection succeeded without taking care of the content of the certificate. So first try that.

Comment: You can try MiTM as Patrick says, also you can inspect traffic after it is decrypted.